# PHP - Loop two columns, one at a time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a few questions and answers stored in the same table. Column Q and A.

```
----ID----Q----A----
   1   |  Q1  | A1 |
   2   |  Q2  | A2 |
   3   |  Q3  | A3 |
```

I want to echo all questions into a div slider and all answers into another div slider.

Something like this:

```
<div>
<ul>
<li>Question 1</li>
<li>Question 2</li>
<li>Question 3</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div>
<ul>
<li>Answer 1</li>
<li>Answer 2</li>
<li>Answer 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Im selecting all rows order by RAND, otherwise I would just run the selection again (n00b style). 
How do I perform this loop, starting with first column continue with next in correct order?
My knowledge in PHP is quite limited.

Code (how Im used to print tables):

```
<ul id="fade">
<?php
$num = "100";
$questions = "SELECT * FROM quiz ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $num";


$result = mysql_query($questions, $dbconnection);

for ($i=0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
$rank = 1;
}

  while($myRow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo "<li>" .$myRow['q']. "</li>";
  echo "<li>" .$myRow['a']. "</li>";
  rank++;       
  }
  ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [*red box*](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @Charles: some of the words in your comment aren't links yet :-(

Comment: @zerkms, they all seem to work for me.  That's a c&p from the stock link guide in room 11...

Comment: @Charles: it was irony - my point was that you've had so many links so that it's less black words rather than blue :-)

Comment: brb, linking every unlinked word to a dictonary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `echo` them right away you could do add the questions to one array and the answers to another:

```
$questions = Array();
$answers = Array();

while($myRow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $questions[] = $myRow['q'];
  $answers[] = $myRow['a']; 
 }
```

And then build the `ul`s:

```
foreach($question as $q){
    echo "<li>" . $q . "<li>";
}
```

...

```
foreach($answer as $a){
    echo "<li>" . $a . "<li>";
}
```

Or something similar based on your needs.

Comment: Instead of `array_push`, use the [`[]` syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying) to add elements to the end.  Instead of the clunky `for` loop, use [`foreach`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to iterate over the members of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$q = "";
$a = "";
while($myRow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $q .= "<li>" .$myRow['q']. "</li>";
  $a .= "<li>" .$myRow['a']. "</li>";
}

echo "<div><ul>$q</ul></div>";
echo "<div><ul>$a</ul></div>";
```